# Add arg0 in logback DB Appender spring boot

Tags: java, spring, logback, spring-logback

I am using logback with sprint boot, I have a DB appender and it works fine but I can't edit arg0, arg1...etc in logging_event table, how can I add values in these fields ?

Comment: log.info("value {} is updated to {}",value1, value2);

Answer (score -1):

```
log.info(dbMarker, "formatted_message", "arg0");
```

Comment: This is not supported format in logback implementation of org.slf4j.Logger